# Getting error After launching the chrome driver through Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, jasmine, protractor

After Launching the browser, I got the following error.

> Failed: script timeout
>             (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
>           Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '----'
>           System info: host: '-----', ip: '-----', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
>           Driver info: driver.version: unknown

I tried with

```
yarn install
webdriver-manager update
```

still didn't work

Contents of protractor.conf.js

```
capabilities: { 
    browserName: 'chrome', 
    shardTestFiles: false, 
    maxInstances: 3, 
    chromeOptions: { 
        args: [ 'disable-infobars=true', 'start-maximized=true' ], 
        prefs: { 
            'credentials_enable__service': false, 
            download: { 
                prompt_for_download: false, 
                directory_upgrade: true, 
                default_directory: process.cwd() + '\\src\\downloads' 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the full content of your protractor.conf.js file. That way we might be able to help you better

Comment: capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: false,
    maxInstances: 3,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'disable-infobars=true',
        'start-maximized=true'
      ],
      prefs: {
        'credentials_enable__service': false,
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          directory_upgrade: true,
          default_directory: process.cwd() + '\\src\\downloads'
        }
      }
    }
  }, This is the content of my protractor.conf.js

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: this can't be full context of conf.js. Its even missing `exports.config` statement, so protractor will not even see this as config file

Comment: export let config: Config = {

  specs: ['./**/**/*.js'],
  
  resultJsonOutputFile: 'result.json',
  framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    print: function () { }
  },

  

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

  
 
  onPrepare: async () => {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true,
      },
    }));
 
   This is the other part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. clone the repository through git extension.
2. update yarn, node modules and java
3. Run the commands: 
   a)yarn install && yarn run webdriver-manager update
   b) yarn tsc

this worked for me. try it Mate.

Comment: Thanks will try it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the "selenium" folder present inside "../node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\"
2. webdriver-manager update
3. Check "update-config.json" file present inside "../node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium" and check is it update with chromedriver version and correct path.

sometimes update-config.json file not update with correct version and path.
protractor use this file to get chromedriver version.

Worked for me.
Let try this!